# bridging RPi wlan0, eth0 and getting internt through eth1(USB Modem)

Tags: raspbian

I want to configure My Raspberry Pi the same way.

1. I have a USB Modem (D-LINK 3G MiFi) which connect to Internet via 3G
   and shows a eth1 in Raspberry Pi and works perfectly to provide
   internet
2. I want to connect my LAN device (old pc) to eth0
3. I want to connect my WiFi devices to wlan0
4. I am able to connect my eth0 device to internet and able to
   configure wlan0 as HOSTAPD mode.

I want to share same Netwrok to eth0 and wlan0 I want to access internet for devices connected on eth0 and wlan0

How shall i configure wlan0 as it shall be on same network to communicate between devices and to internet.

Answer (score 1):

Software packages you need: `bridge-utils`, `isc-dhcp-server`, `bind9`, `hostapd`

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    post-up service hostapd start

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.22.0.1
    gateway 255.255.255.192
    bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
    post-up service isc-dhcp-server start

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf (`isc-dhcp-server`)

```
option domain-name-servers 10.22.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
authoritative;
subnet 10.22.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.192
{
    range 10.22.0.32 10.22.0.62;
    option routers 10.22.0.1;
}
```

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server (`isc-dhcp-server`)

```
INTERFACES="br0"
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_dynaddr=1
```

---

I have a similar configuration, with a Raspberry Pi functioning as a residential wireless router, dialing up using PPPoE over EPON to my ISP.

Comment: Hi,It shows unknown options dhcp.dns-servers option dns-servers 192.

Comment: @ForGuru I typed this answer out of the back of my head so it may have errors. Fixed in the edit.

Comment: Try to describe what those configs mean and do to help the OP understand and customize them.